# How to Increment variables dynamically?

Tags: linux

Source file having:

```
AAA BBB CCC DDD
XXX ZZZ YYY FFF
```

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
        for n in `seq 1 4`
                do
                vr[$n]=$(echo -e "$line" | awk '{print $'$n'}')
                #test
                vr[$n]=${vr[$n]}
                echo ${vr[$n]}
                export ${vr[$n]}
        done
done < rst.txt
```

I have to these values outside of the loop.
Dynamically increment variables and store the values like,

```
data_vr[1]=AAA
data_vr[2]=BBB
data_vr[3]=CCC
data_vr[4]=DDD
and 
default_vr[1]=XXX
default_vr[2]=ZZZ
default_vr[3]=YYY
default_vr[4]=FFF
```

I have to these values outside of the loop.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must "import" the value of `$n` valirable in to the `awk` environment. Probably something like can help you:

```
vr[$n]=$(echo -e "$line" | awk -F\, -v n=$n '{print $n}')
```

Comment: It is working. Thanks a lot.  I can able to build my requirement.

Comment: Romeo Ninov, my file having "," comma Delimeter so where can we add filed separator to the command. Please suggest me.

Comment: @Harisha, please check my edited answer